# Merging multiple ajax responses into a single array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of item names, that I am looping through and calling the function below. I need the results of each ajax call to be added to the main array, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that. Ideally I would also display a loading message (using jquery to show/hide when it's done, then display the data), but I'm not sure where to start.

```
var list = ["node1","node2","node3"]

var items = [];

$.each(list, function( index, value ) {
  getNodes(value.name);
});

function getNodes(name) {

    jQuery.ajax( {
        url: 'http://url.com' + name + '/endpoint',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
          if ( data.length > 0 ) {            
            jQuery.each( data, function event( key, value ) {

              var info = [];
              info.name = name;
              info.address = this.address;
              info.node = this.node.data;

              items = $.extend(items[name],info);

            } );

          }
        },
        error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
          alert( 'An error has occured!' );
        }
    } );
}
```

My end goal is to have a single array/object that I can (once done) loop through and act on that data in javascript/jquery.

```
   [{
        "node1": [{
            "node1a": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.4",
                "node": "somedata"
            },
            "node1b": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.5",
                "node": "somedata"
            },
            "node1c": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.6",
                "node": "somedata"
            }
        }],
        "node2": [{
            "node2a": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.7",
                "node": "somedata"
            },
            "node2b": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.8",
                "node": "somedata"
            },
            "node2c": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.9",
                "node": "somedata"
            }
        }],
        "node3": [{
            "node3a": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.10",
                "node": "somedata"
            },
            "node3b": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.11",
                "node": "somedata"
            },
            "node3c": {
                "name": "node1",
                "address": "192.168.1.12",
                "node": "somedata"
            }
        }]
    }]
```

The issue Im having is that it seems like any array I try to build isn't done populating when I call the function to process the finished data, so it returns empty. Beyond that, I'm not sure what it is that I am doing is called, to search for help doing it. Maybe async, or promises? Need pointed in the right direction.

Comment: In this case, `AJAX` call must be `synchronous`, then only you can able to merge their result.

Comment: And I would love to learn if there is any other way of achieving this.

Comment: Please post your code so that it also contains where you process the finished data. Indeed since the ajax is asynchronous, you'll need to use promises (or async/await) so that you know when all of the async calls have finished.

Comment: You are using array's were you are meaning to use a regular object, eg `info` should be an object since you aren't adding elements to it, just object properties. Also `items[name]` if `name` isn't some number you are not setting/accessing an array element but just some object property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a transpiler you can use `async/await` with `Promise`. It makes it easier to reason how the code will act. Example below of how you could possibly go about it.

```
for(let x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
  const result = await getNodes(list[x]);
  items.push(result);
}

function async getNodes(name) {
  const url = 'http://url.com' + name + '/endpoint';
  return await ajaxCall(url);
}


function ajaxCall(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jQuery.ajax( {
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
      resolve(data);
    },
    error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      reject('error');
    }
   } );
  });
}
```

Comment: `jQuery.ajax` already returns a Promise-like object - I'm pretty sure there's no need to wrap it in another.

Comment: I wasn't sure if one could use `await` with Jquery's Promise-like type. But yes, if you can then you can just return it.